# How to set default values with methods in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, default-value

How to compute the value for default value in object fields in Odoo 8 **models.py**

We can't use the `_default` attribute anymore in Odoo 8.

```python
field_name = fields.datatype(
    string=’value’, 
    default=compute_default_value
)
```

In the above field declaration, I want to call a method to assign default value for that field. For example:

```python
name = fields.Char(
    string='Name', 
    default= _get_name()
)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a lambda function like this:

```
name = fields.Char(
    string='Name',
    default=lambda self: self._get_default_name(),
)

@api.model
def _get_default_name(self):
    return "test"
```

Comment: It work but it can be done in a simpler way. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to follow the [OCA guidelines](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#field) and follow de conventions you can check that the "Fields declarations" are always above the "Default methods". If you declare the function as you wrote in your post you can't do it like that

Comment: They have changed the order as you can see. [Order 1](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/blob/repos_with_ids-website/CONTRIBUTING.md), [Order 2](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#field). But I am still thinking that to write all the methods after the fields definitions is a better organization

Comment: good solution ... if i want to change default value based on another field value

Comment: @omarahmed you can use `@api.onchange('other_field')`, the `other_field` must be added to the form

Answer (score 15):

A simpler version for the @ChesuCR answer:

```
def _get_default_name(self):
    return "test"

name = fields.Char(
    string='Name',
    default=_get_default_name,
)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel Reis, I am getting into loop while trying this. Nothing Happens

Comment: Ist is possible to do this with many2many fields. I am trying to inherit the tag_ids field like this but keep getting errors.